# OEM Windows 7 key with downloaded ISO?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, iso-image, oem

I'm going to reinstall my Windows 7, but when I bought this PC it came with Windows 7 preinstalled and the product key is on a sticker on the PC's case. I have downloaded a Windows 7 Home Premium ISO file from [here](http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65733/X15-65733.iso) and I do believe that this download is legal as I found it from superuser.com a while ago. What I'm asking is: will I be able to use my OEM key to install Windows 7 from this ISO file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will work as long as you are installing the edition you have the key for. For example, if you have the key for Windows 7 Home Premium it will work if the downloaded image is of Windows 7 Home Premium. Service Pack doesn't matter.

Comment: I have to note that they won't work if the builds don't match, e.g. Home Premium VL and Home Premium MSDN can't share keys.

Comment: I read from somewhere that if i use an OEM key on a non OEM install disc i would need to call Microsoft for activation. Is this correct?

Comment: @user1365830 Here is what Microsoft forums say: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/can-an-oem-licence-key-be-used-to-activate-a/495b4da1-c1b7-4d93-82a9-8c8601bbaf32

Comment: Seems like this program may do the trick: http://directedge.us/content/abr-activation-backup-and-restore

Comment: @arielnmz Home Premium does not have a VL version.

Comment: @kinokijuf my bad, it was just meant for the example, I just used the same edition Cornelius used on his answer.

Comment: @user1365830 Vista and above do not have separate OEM discs.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the accepted answer: maybe.

It all depends on the `ei.cfg` file found within the Windows ISO which will state whether or not the image is treated as an OEM version or a full retail version.

If you try to use an OEM licence key with a retail version then it will install, but won't register and activate - and vice versa.

However all is not lost, you can change an ISO between the two types by using the information posted at [Reinstall Windows 7: OEM or Standard?](https://superuser.com/questions/742927/reinstall-windows-7-oem-or-standard/743089#743089)