# Windows 7 Product Key for Download Windows 7 Disc Images (ISO Files)

Tags: windows-7, windows, iso-image, product-key

I lost my Windows 7 Product Key , so I restored it by software as [Belarc](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) and [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) , both them gave my the same Product Key .

Now I try to [Download Windows 7 Disc Images (ISO Files)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7) , and I asked to enter my Windows Product Key (25 characters)  , after I enter it , the request verification notify me -

> Error
>
> We encountered a problem with the product key you provided. Please try
>   again or visit the Microsoft Support Contact Us page for assistance.

Does it absolutely indicate that my Product Key is wrong or maybe this link not support all the licenses?

**Edit:**

I found that for an arbitrary Product Key I type it give another error message  -

> Error
>
> We encountered a problem with the validation request.

Maybe it not allowed the verify with it on the same time I use it ?

**Edit 2:**

My computer came with pre-installed Windows  , probably OEM licence .

Comment: If you're sure you didn't mistype something and you entered the key correctly, and the key hasn't been used on multiple installations, you'll probably have to contact Microsoft as the error indicates.

Comment: This Product Key is currently  used by my Windows , does it impossible to download the ISO before formatting my computer ?

Comment: The windows download you linked is for non oem installs only. You need an oem iso image which Microsoft no longer supplies. A Dell install dvd should work with the product key from the coa sticker on the pc. product key retrieved using belarc or other software's will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the current Windows came pre-installed with the computer, then the key you retrieved might be the generic OEM key, which won't work for downloading images. There might be a unique OEM key (different from the installed one) somewhere on a sticker or in the OEM documentation. You may try to use that one for download, but even that it's not guaranteeed to work.

From [New ways to get free Windows-installation media](http://windowssecrets.com/top-story/new-ways-to-get-free-windows-installation-media/):

> The new Win7 Software Recovery Center
>
> Microsoft’s newly launched “Software Recovery Center” (site; see Figure 6) currently serves only users who have purchased retail versions of Win7.

Note the emphasis on *retail*.

See also [OEM Windows 7 key with downloaded ISO?](https://superuser.com/questions/774570/oem-windows-7-key-with-downloaded-iso?rq=1) and the links posted in the discussion.

Comment: Indeed my Windows came pre-installed with the computer , does my restored Product Key would be legal for re-installing ?

Comment: @URL87 Legal, yes. But - at least officially - it's only guaranteed to work with recovery media (DVD or ISO) provided by the OEM. Most reputable OEMs will provide such recovery media for free, or a small nominal fee. That said, OEM keys *may* work with retail ISOs, as discussed in more detail in the other SU question linked at the end of my answer.

Comment: You can convert a retail version of Windows 7 to an OEM version by modifying a file on the installation media. See http://superuser.com/questions/742927/reinstall-windows-7-oem-or-standard/743089#743089 for steps to do this.