# Windows 7 doesn't accept product key

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've got a laptop that came without operating system and Windows 7 Home Premium were installed on it later using CD (which I do not have)

Its' HDD started running slow, so we've decided to upgrade it to SSD.

I've found what's the CD Key using [Nirisoft ProductKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html)

That's the result:

```
Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1
Product Part No.: X15-0000
Installed from 'OEM' media.
Product ID: 00000-00000-00000-00000  match to CD Key data
CD Key: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
Computer Name: LAPTOP
Registered Owner: Owner
Registered Organization:
```

However, I cannot download ISO file from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7) page if I enter my CD Key. I've downloaded another installation media from internet, however it does not accept my key as well once I installed it on SSD.

How can I download a ISO file that would accept this or make cd key work?

Comment: You'll need an OEM disk that matches your OEM key, Microsoft does not provide OEM images for download.

Comment: So it means that my OEM key is useless without OEM disk?..

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft).  The only reason it wouldn't work is if the .ISO was for the wrong version of Windows 7  The license key you should be using is on the COA sticker.

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting.  See these for some info on changing a Retail disk image into an OEM (if you can get a hold of a retail disk): [Related](http://superuser.com/a/774888/23133), [Related](http://superuser.com/a/743089/23133).  The "real way" would be contact your OEM to get correct replacement media from them.

Comment: Yes, Ramhound's link, you can try activating after install by searching 'Activate' in start.  That will give you a phone number, call, wait an hour, finally talk to someone.  If it truly is a legal key they may unlock it for you, or give you a replacement.  They may try to sell you a new key for $40 or so.  Also, you'll have to talk to like 3 people and read that 25 character key several times to most likely someone that is not very good at whatever language you speak.