# Where to Get Windows 7 64 Pro OEM

Tags: windows-7, iso-image, oem

I have Problems with my Lenovo notebook, and I want to reinstall windows 7 64 bit Pro. I downloaded the Iso but was not able to activate via the OEM key under my battery. 
since digitalriver is down, where do I get the Windows OEM versions?

Comment: [What you downloaded should work](http://superuser.com/questions/742927/reinstall-windows-7-oem-or-standard/743089#743089)

Comment: I also tried http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery  ,where this came out; The product key you entered appears to be for software that was pre-installed on a device.  Please contact the device manufacturer for software recovery options.

Comment: What you downloaded should already work.  You just have to modify it so it does.

Comment: how do I modify it?

Comment: I already provided that information.

Comment: Ok, sorry, i didn't notice that your comment is a link. Thanks. I'll try that

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303: the Post You commented does not work. Digitalriver is down, and the site from Microsoft does not accept the oem Key.